# After integrating Capacitor into Ionic project unable to run in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, capacitor, npx

Finally I have made the change to move from Ionic DevApp to Capacitor, the process went well with integrating the Capacitor capabilities in the project with commands `ionic integrations enable capacitor, npx cap init [appName] [appId] & ionic build`. So to try it out I have to add a platform first so I added iOS with `npx cap add ios` was going well until it stumbled across the following error :

```
✖ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod install" (may take several minutes): 
✖ update ios: 
[error] Error running update: Analyzing dependencies
Cloning spec repo `trunk` from `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` named `trunk`.
You can try adding it manually in `/Users/flameswitcher/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin18/rbconfig.rb:215: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
```

I tried what the error suggests me to do but says `trunk` is a reserved keyword for cocoa pods... And have no idea what that means cause I'm not familiar with iOS development. Anyone who can assist me with this please I need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by updating RubyGems by running `gem update --system` and uninstalled CocoaPods and installed them again heres the process:

```
gem list --local | grep cocoapods
# You'll get an output similar to this one
# cocoapods (1.9.0)
# cocoapods-core (1.9.0, 1.8.3, 1.2.1)
# cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.4)
# cocoapods-downloader (1.2.2)
# cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
# cocoapods-search (1.0.0)
# cocoapods-stats (1.1.0)
# cocoapods-trunk (1.4.1)
# cocoapods-try (1.1.0)
```

From that uninstall `cocoapods` with command `gem uninstall cocoapods` which may ask you if you also want to remove it's dependencies or not if it does press 'Y', if you are not asked you'll have to uninstall the gems you've retrieved from the command above.

Then installed it again by following this amazing [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEAjvNRdZa0&spfreload=10), lastly `cd` into my project then ran the command `npx cap open ios` then everything was FINE!

I hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: I deleted cocoapods and all dependencies below. This is what I did : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60884826/unable-to-add-a-source-with-url-https-cdn-cocoapods-org-named-trunk

Comment: gem uninstall cocoapods / and gem uninstall cocoapods-xxxxxx
and with the "sudo" mode too

Comment: So after doing so what error do you get when you try again?

Comment: the same : Unable to add a source with url `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` named `trunk`.

Comment: Would you mind pasting it all in, perhaps there might be something else, or someone might try to help.

Comment: The youtube video is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually install cocoapods and then add ios capacitor dependency. Please follow the steps below and issue will be fixed.

Step-1: Install the following using sudo access

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Step-2: Add ios dependency as below

```
npx cap add ios
```