# Unable to add a source with url `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` named `trunk`

Tags: ios, cocoapods, capacitor

I'm building an app with capacitor for ios. When I launch the command 'npx cap sync ios'
(which launch `pod install`) and I get this error :

```
✖ Updating iOS native dependencies with "pod install" (may take several minutes): 
✖ update ios: 
[error] Error running update: Analyzing dependencies
Cloning spec repo `trunk` from `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` named `trunk`.
You can try adding it manually in `/Users/damien/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

If i execute the recommandation :

```
pod repo add trunk https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

I get this error

```
[!] Repo name `trunk` is reserved for CocoaPods' main spec repo accessed via CDN.
```

I'm blocked on this issue since 6 hours. I read all post mentionning this error on internet.

Comment: What’s your CocoaPods version?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I got the same issue. I tried `pod repo add master https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`, not working. I tried add `source https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` in Podfile, not working, I tried `pod repo remove  trunk`, `pod repo add trunk https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`. Neither works.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Temporary solution :

I added `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' on the top of my Podfile

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
....
```

But it takes 30 minutes to download all the repo (2.5gb) in my `Users/damien/.cocoapods/repos/` folder

Comment: I had to do this too :( I get an SSL error from the command line trying to connect to the CDN, though I can use CURL or open the files in the browser without a problem. This started after updating to Catalina and then updating my cocoapods version

Comment: I had an openssl error too, after updated it. tTo avoid it, I downgraded the version with `brew switch openssl 1.0.2q`

Comment: I have the same problem, it just broke, maybe the service is just down at the moment.

Comment: Worked for me with v1.9.3

Comment: I got a different error after this. `Unable to find a specification for 'React-Core' depended upon by 'RNCPushNotificationIOS'`. already ran `pod repo update`. still not working. any ideas?

Comment: i am getting this error - [!] The 'Pods-RNNativebase' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: (Flipper-Boost-iOSX and Flipper-RSocket)

Answer (score 17):

You can restore `trunk` using:

```
pod repo add-cdn trunk https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

found at: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10078#issuecomment-696481185

Comment: I get this error [!] CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: 500 
<html>
<head>
<title>Fastly error: unknown domain cdn.cocoapods.org</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Fastly error: unknown domain: cdn.cocoapods.org. Please check that this domain has been added to a service.</p>
<p>Details: cache-hhn4056-HHN</p></body></html>

Comment: Me same, it looks like this url has been deprecated.

Comment: https://status.cocoapods.org/ There is a status page you can see if stuff is running. Right now CDN is down due to DNS issues.

Comment: I got this error `CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: Unsupported protocol`.

Comment: I got this. ```[!] CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: 403 <!DOCTYPE html>```

Answer (score 9):

I just solved this with a `sudo gem update`

Comment: Helped me on M1. Couldn't run 'pod install' because of llvm, ffi issues. Reinstalled cocoapods, llvm, ffi (x86, arm64) but nothing helped. Only 'sudo gem update' solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  I just spent like 6 hours trying to solve this issue.  I guess that's what I get for only looking at the top three answers, even when they're three years old.

Comment: That worked for me also on a M1 macbook. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Another way you can get it working locally since this CDN is an issue

```
pod repo remove trunk
```

In Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

# source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
```

found at:https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10078

Answer (score 2):

If you still have issues after changing the source in your `Podfile`:

`source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`

Its because you need to remove the current "trunk" and re-install pods with `--repo-update`:

```
pod repo remove trunk
pod install --repo-update
```

OR `--clean-install` to execute a full pod installation ignoring the content of the project cache:

```
pod install --clean-install
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed according to [what Logan says on Github](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9595#issuecomment-627636925):

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
gem install cocoapods -v 1.8
pod install
```

It seems that there's a bug or something with 1.9.1!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and found this [post](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11355#issuecomment-1623887921) that solved my problem.

From **nvahalik**

> What ended up working for me was updating ethon to 0.16.0

Just do:

```
sudo gem update ethon
```